# How 'Greedy' of Regex works

Tags: regex

Here is a very simple regex:-

```
kabk
k(.*)k
result:
kabk has 1 group:
ab
```

What I normally do is the following, which is right but unnecessary.

```
k([^k]*)k
```

Can anyone explain to me how the regex parser work? Is the `.*` supposed to consume as much as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `*` operator is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and will capture as many valid characters as it can.

For example, the pattern `k(.*)k` applied to `kkkkak` will capture `kkka`.

You can make an operator non-greedy with the `?` operator.

So the pattern `k(.*?)k` applied to `kkkkak` will capture *nothing*, because the smallest non-greedy match is to allow nothing between the first two `k` characters.

In reply to your comment, the existance of the final `k` in the pattern means that it needs to leave as much as possible to still match a `k` after consuming as much as possible.

Comment: @user764357 here is a suggestion to simplify your excellent example. String `kkkkakbbb` will give the following results:  
GREEDY PATTERN: `/k.*k/` will return **kkkkak**.  `*` is greedy, and will keep searching till it no longer matches)
NON-GREEDY PATTERN: `/k.*?k/` will return **kk**kkak. `*?` is non-greedy, and will return as soon as the complete match is found)

Answer (score 2):

In `kabk`, there's only two `k`s. So it's not proper example to learn about greedy match.

Let's try it with different example: `kabkxyk`

Greedy version match returns `kabkxyk` (`.*` advances before the last `k`): (Followng is javascript):

```
'kabkxyk'.match(/k.*k/)
// ["kabkxyk"]
```

while non-greedy version match returns `kabk`:

```
'kabkxyk'.match(/k.*?k/)
// ["kabk"]
```

Comment: Thanks. if put greed aside, why not .* in my example consume all the character after the first 'k', which find no match.

Comment: @leon, The regular expression `.*` match greedily **as long as the entire pattern matches**.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see `k([^k]*)k` (matching using negation) first on regex101.com debugger::

```
1   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
2   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
3   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
4   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
5   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
6   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
7   /k([^k]*)k/ kabk
#   Match found in 7 steps.
```

Now lets see `k(.*)k` (matching using geedy match) on same regex101.com debugger:

```
1   /k(.*)k/ kabk
2   /k(.*)k/ kabk
3   /k(.*)k/ kabk
4   /k(.*)k/ kabk
5   /k(.*)k/ kabk
6   /k(.*)k/ kabk BACKTRACK
7   /k(.*)k/ kabk BACKTRACK
8   /k(.*)k/ kabk
9   /k(.*)k/ kabk
#   Match found in 9 steps.
```

Clearly first regex is much more efficient in longer strings as there is no BACKTRACKing involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.*` is greedy.  It matches as much as it can.

`.*?` is non-greedy, or parsimonious.  It matches as little as it can.

If you match "bananas" against `ba.*a`, it will match `banana`.

If you match "bananas" against `ba.*?a`, it will match `bana`.